# Resteasy/JAX-RS URL Encoding @PATH

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I am trying to build a client for a restful webservice with Resteasy. The issue is with my client code(below)

```
@Path("solr")
public interface TestClient{

    @GET
    @Path(value="select?indent...")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    ClientResponse<String> getStuff();
}
```

The problem is that the `?` in the `@Path` annotation is automatically URL encoded to a `%3F`. This is in keeping with the javadocs [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/Path.html), but it's causing me to get 404 errors. I tried overriding this with the `encode=false` [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Encoded_and_encoding) but that just creates compiler errors. Is there a way to override or escape this?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think you need a `?` in the Path? It seems like `@QueryParam` is what you'd want instead. See http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html